# How to query/persist joda-time DateTime field using DataNucleus

Tags: java, jpa, jodatime, datanucleus

I recently switched to DataNucleus and noticed that a joda-time DateTime field declared in an entity is not getting persisted. I get the following error:

```
Field 'time' is not marked as persistent so cannot be queried.
```

It is not clear from the documentation if I need to annotate this field or do something else to mark it as persistent.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The [DN docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/types.html) say that types not specified in the JPA spec (e.g org.joda.*) are not persistent by-default. So annotate them with something like @Basic and they ought to be picked up. See our [tests](http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/test/accessplatform/trunk/test.jpa.general/src/test/org/datanucleus/tests/types/JodaTimeTest.java?revision=15445&view=markup) and [samples](http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/test/accessplatform/trunk/test.jpa.general/src/java/org/datanucleus/samples/types/jodatime/) if in doubt